# Extract Data from XML column

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I'm using Postgresql vs 13 on windows. pgAdmin as editor.

I have a table with xml records and IDs. I want to extract the XML data into the items tags below is what I have.

```
ID  || xml
--------------   
 1  ||"<order>
          <date> 1/20/2020 </date>
          <delivery> yes </delivery>
          <items>
          <item>
          <name> fried chicken dinner </name>
          <quantity> 1 </quantity>
          <price> 8.00 </price>
          </item>
          <item>
          <name> Coke </name>
          <quantity> 2 </quantity>
          <price> 2.50 </price>
          </item>
          <item>
          <name> Mashed Potatoes </name>
          <quantity> 1 </quantity>
          <price> 4.00 </price>
          </item>
          </items>
          </order>"
```

I want something like this:

```
ID  || Name                 || Quantity || Price
-----------------------------------------------------   
 1  || fried chicken dinner || 1        || 8.00
 1  ||   Coke               || 2        || 2.50
 1  ||   Mashed Potatoes    || 1        || 4.00
```

I think I need to use Row ID:

```
SELECT row_number() over () as id, orders_data as orders from orders
```

But I'm not sure how to unpack xml column without using xmltable and I'd like to avoid it.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with the `XMLTABLE`? That's the way to do what you need.